# Remove list of recently updated apps in Mac App Store

Tags: mac-appstore

How would you remove the list of recently updated applications in the Mac App Store?

*(the part selected in red in the screenshot)*

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can remove that section.  However, you can hide/unhide your MAS purchases on an individual basis.  Is that something you'd like to do?

Comment: If the consequence is that they disappear from the section I show, yes, I'd like that. Otherwise no. :/ My unique goal is to remove the updates from the list which is selected in my screenshot, the "Last 30 days" list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit or remove the file ~/Library/Application Support/App Store/updatejournal.plist.

The file contains all updates installed lately, but is also cleaned by the system regularly.

Answer (score 1):

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202320).

If you hide an item you purchased in the Mac App Store, you won't get update notifications for it, and you won't see it on your Purchases page. If you're using Family Sharing, hidden items will also be hidden from your family members.

### Hide purchases using these steps:

1. Open the Mac App Store.
2. Choose `Store > Sign In`, then enter your Apple ID and password.
3. Click Purchases.
4. Right-click the item that you want to hide and choose **Hide Purchase**. A prompt will ask if you're sure that you want to hide the item.
   Click the Hide Purchase button. The item will fade. The item below it, if there is one, will replace it in the list.[image]

### Unhide purchases using these steps:

1. Open the Mac App Store.
2. Choose `Store > Sign In`, then enter your Apple ID and password, if you're not already signed in.
3. Choose Store > View My Account.
4. Enter your Apple ID password, if prompted.
5. From the Account Information page, click **View Hidden Purchases**.[image]

Comment: Thanks, this will be helpful for other cases, but unfortunately it doesn't remove the hidden app from the list of recently updated apps. Great tip nonetheless.

Comment: Sorry, this was as close as I could find and I thought it would work.  If it doesn't help your issue, I can delete it.

Comment: It doesn't solve my issue, I just tried. But this is a good tip, related to the question. I don't know if you should delete it. I'll let you judge of that. ;)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll leave it in the hopes it helps others who might have a similar issue and get here using the search.  Hopefully, someone will be able to provide an answer that better addresses your problem.